# Why does FireFox does not always select the correct event target? (Path Element Specifically)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am not sure if this is a bug in firefox or what not, but I am having a problem that only exists firefox.

I have the html code below:

```
<div id="Div1"></div>   
<div id="mydiv">
   <div style="height: 590px;">
      <svg id="mySvg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 8000;">
         <g>
            <path stroke="black" d="M50,123L1400,323" style="stroke-width: 10; opacity: 1;">  </path>
         </g>
      </svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

Using javascript / jquery, I am trying to handle the mousemove event:

```
$("#mydiv").mousemove(function (x) {
  Div1.innerHTML = x.target.tagName;
});
```

The problem I have is that even when the mouse is on top of the line, it does not always shows the path as the event target tagName.

Please note:

1. This does not seems to be a problem when the angle of the path is
   (0 degrees)
2. This does not seems to be a problem when line is
   short
3. As mentioned, this is not a problem in IE9 nor in Chrome
   v24.  I am testing with FireFox v18.

I have created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxEYV/3/) for review.

If at all possible, please let me know if I am doing something wrong, or if there is a workaround for this problem.

Thank you for all the help

Comment: There's another issue with it. If I slide the mouse along your path it keep on jumping between 'svg' and 'path', while it should remain 'path' as I never move my mouse out of it. # ps. As I used to say: Firefox: a 21st century equivalent of the infamous IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has been posted before and it is related to a bug in firefox.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676001